# C++ template function not working in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

I'm practicing a template example. Here's the code:

```
//template_practice.h
#pragma once

template<typename T, unsigned N> 
void print_arry(ostream &out,const T (&arry)[N]) 
{
    for (T* i = cbegin(arry); i != cend(arry); i++) 
    {
        out << *i << " ";
    }
    out << endl;
}

//main.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int test[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    print_arry<int, 10> (cout, test);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

//stdafx.h
//... (library headers)
#include "template_practice.h"
```

There are many errors, including: "header stop not at file scope. And IntelliSense PCH file was not generated","'ostream': undeclared identifier", "expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have function type"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, add `#include <iostream>` (for `std::ostream` and `std::endl`) and `#include <iterator>` (for `std::cbegin` and `std::cend`) in `template_practice.h`. And add `std::` when use them. (BTW [`using namespace std;` is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3309790)) .

Secondly, `cbegin(arry);` returns `const T*`, so change the type of `i` to `const T*`, or use `auto` instead; e.g. `for (auto i = cbegin(arry); i != cend(arry); i++)`.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/suzLbriUkZDvGyY5)

Comment: @yughred you also don't need `<int, 10>`: `print_arry` can deduce the template arguments from the type of what you passed in.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.